# project management software in android

Tags: android, project-management

I have to develop a project management software for a Android tab.

Basically a Gantt chart drawing software. I have no Idea where to start and what is the external API that I should use to draw a Gantt chart. So please some one tell me the external API that I should use and some references which will help me to start a project management software for android. Thank you All thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

Come on man! If you have sound Java (or programming) knowledge, I am sure you understand that not one is going to "point" you to external APIs or a project template where you just need to change a couple of Strings and voila! you have your project.

Nevertheless, here's a good answer from https://stackoverflow.com/a/772757/619699 for the charting part. I'd assume these charts do Gantt support too. You'd have to check their documentation.

> UPDATE
>
> Since this question was asked a few very nice open source native
>   libraries have been created. These include:
>
> ChartDroid AndroidPlot AChartEngine ORIGINAL
>
> It looks like the creator of this question solved this problem and
>   posted some interesting stuff about it to the Internet. I've linked to
>   his solution along with several others that exist now.
>
> rapidandroid (question creator solution) GraphView Java Charts for
>   Android Just to summarize: his solution involved using a JavaScript
>   library (flot) built on top of jQuery. This library was then included
>   in an HTML page which was loaded into a custom WebView. The custom
>   WebView then read data from a custom Java class made accessible to
>   JavaScript code via the WebView.addJavascriptInterface method. Details
>   can be found at the above link.
>
> The other solutions may present a more straightforward approach.

Comment: the link doesn't work